# Is the following function a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am trying to find out if the following function is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^2}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R^3}$.

**T**: $\mathbb{R^2}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R^3}$, T $\left( 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
 \right) =$
$\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
0 \\
2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I know for a function to be a linear transformation the following two conditons must hold:

Given **u,v** $\in M_{2,1}$ (The 1st vector space, an analog for $\mathbb{R^2}$) & c$\in \mathbb{R}$ then:

1. T(**u** + **v**) = T(**u**) + T(**v**)
2. T(c**u**) = cT(**u**)

I claimed the function was indeed a linear transformation and denoted **u,v** as:

**u** =
$\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
and **v** =
$\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

I then showed T(**u** + **v**) = T(**u**) + T(**v**)

$\to T(u + v) = T\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 + v_1 \\
u_2 + v_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}\right)
= \begin{bmatrix}
2(u_1+v_1) \\
0 \\
2(u_2+v_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\to T(u) = T\left( 
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \right)
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
2(u_1) \\
0 \\
2(u_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
T(v) = \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \right)
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2(v_1) \\
0 \\
2(v_2) \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

By inspection $T(u,v) = T(u) +T(v) \implies$ Condition 1 holds

Next I showed T(c**u**) = cT(**u**)

$\to T\left( c
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \right) =
T\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
c(u_1) \\
c(u_2) \\
\end{bmatrix} \right) =
\begin{bmatrix}
2c(u_1) \\
0 \\
2c(u_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$ \to cT \left(
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \right) = 
c
\begin{bmatrix}
2(u_1) \\
0 \\
2(u_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2c(u_1) \\
0 \\
2c(u_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Thus T(c**u**) = cT(**u**) $\implies$ Condition 2 holds

I think this is right, but I'd like to have confirmation regarding whether the transformation is indeed linear and if the way in which I proved it was sufficiently rigorous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't define a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to another space by defining only the image of one vector. You have to define it on a basis of the vector space.

For sure you can define a linear transformation $T$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $T\bigl([1,1]\bigr)=[2,0,2]$. It is sufficient to complete $[1,1]$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with another vector $v$, linearly independent from $[1,1]$ (for instance with the vector $[1,0]$) and define the image of $v$. In whatever way you define the image of the second vector of the basis you obtain a linear function.

Of course the way you define $T$ on another basis' vector will change the function, but for sure it will be a linear function such that $T\bigl([1,1]\bigr)=[2,0,2]$.

What you did while trying to verifying the linearity of your function is forcing other properties to the function: why should $T([u_1+v_1, u_2+v_2])=[2(u_1+v_1), 0, 2(u_2+v_2)]$? By the only property you stated at the beginning you don't have this equality. A function which maps $[1,1]$ to $[2,0,2]$ is not forced to be linear. Think for instance to the constant function $T(v)=[2,0,2] \ \forall \ v \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

An example of a linear function $T$ which satisfies your property is the following:

Take the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, let's say $B=\bigl\{[1,0],[0,1]\bigr\}$. If you define $T$ by $T\bigl([1,0]\bigr)=[2,0,0]$ and $T\bigl([0,1]\bigr)=[0,0,2]$, then, by linearity of $T$ you have:
$$T\bigl([1,1]\bigr) \ = \ T\bigl([1,0]\bigr)+T\bigl([0,1]\bigr) \ = \ [2,0,0]+[0,0,2]=[2,0,2] \ .$$

This function is represented by the following matrix (the columns are the images of the vectors of the standard basis):
$$\left[\begin{matrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{matrix} \right] \ .$$

You can also swap the images of the two basis vectors and you obtain the same result but a different function.

Comment: would you mind giving an example of a true linear transformation that would satisfy this?  thanks!

Comment: To be clear, if you give the image under T of a linearly independent vector, that will define a linear transform, but the transformation will be defined only under the assumption that it is linear. Asking whether T is linear is either trivial (if it's stated as such, then it is) or not determined by its image on just two vectors (if it's not given as being linear, then we don't know whether it is).

Comment: @ScottEdwards2000 I added the example to the answer

Comment: thanks @SilvioM that helps - I think I was missing the point a bit - as Accumulation stated I guess we are starting out accepting the T function as linear.  I was just wondering what a true linear function that did this would look like, but I guess that is beyond the scope.